# C# Storing player cards Database Design

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm having really hard time figuring out how to store cards each player owns in SQL database. My bets idea so far is to have one table with cards:

```
[id], [cardName]
```

And to associate it with players like that:

```
[id], [playeName], [cardId], [quantity]
```

This setup will allow me to easly add new cards to database (when new cards are available) just by inserting them into card table.

However i'm concerned about player table as it could grow very large quite fast (with set having around 250 cards) it would look like smth like this:

```
1 Bravd fireball 4; 2 Bravd Soldier 2; 3 Bravd PoisonSword 1, 4 John Soldier 3;  .... etc
```

Allowing up to 250 entries by player. I would be really happy having 1000 players as first milestone but that gives at max 250*1000 possible entries, while there would be more players or new sets in future database size would greatly increase

Is this solution acceptable or could somebody recommend better solution?

Comment: 1 million rows is not large....

Comment: imo `cardId` should be an int PK in a table storing `fireball` in a name field, ditto for `playerName`

Comment: I would not be concerned about a maximum size of 250,000 records, this is not a lot in terms of table size. You could even reduce your table to `(PlayerID INT, CardID SMALLINT UNSIGNED, Quantity SMALLINT UNSIGNED)` meaning your rowsize is only 8 bytes, you can still have 65535 different cards, with the same limit for maximum quantity. So your table of 250k rows would take up 1.9MB this is not very large at all!

Comment: I think what OP needs is further normalization possible without having a performance impact

Comment: @MitchWheat Sure it is. It may not be huge, or massive, or global-scale, but it's certainly large.

Comment: @TylerH: no, 1 million rows is tiny. In a properly designed database, anything less than approx. 100 million rows is small.

Comment: @MitchWheat size is relative. Most people who deal with databases never see 1 million rows in a single db. Don't let things like 'big data' skew your perspective of the *whole* world if databases.

Comment: @TylerH : I've been working with databases for over 20 years. I know my craft, some might say quite well.

Comment: @MitchWheat Exactly, so the echo chamber effect is probably very strong :-) When you're summitting Everest, it's easy to forget that most hikers/climbers don't ever go beyond a few thousand feet. A million records could be an entire town's population's whole lifetime of hospital visits, for example. That's a lot of data!

Comment: 1 million rows is not large. Period.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add another table to reduce repeated data for player name:

```
card_table -> [card_id], [cardName]
player_table -> [player_id] , [playerName]  
player_card_table -> [player_id],[card_id],[qty]
```